# Twitter typeahead.js 0.11.1 prefetch not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-typeahead

I'm trying to prefetch a whole JSON database (55kb) for using it with typeahead.js 0.11.1. I'm struggling the whole day with this and I found the typeahead.js documentation pretty basic for that matter.

my JSON looks something like this:

```
[{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Green"
}, {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Red"
}, {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Blue"
}]
```

and the javascript:

```
$(function() {

    var tagSuggestion = new Bloodhound({
        datumTokenizer: function(d) {
            return Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace(d.name);
        },
        queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
        limit: 10,
        prefetch: {
            url: 'ajax.json-colors.php'
        }
    });

    $('.typeahead').typeahead({
        hint: true,
        highlight: true,
        minLength: 2
    }, {
        name: 'tagSuggestion',
        displayKey: 'name',
        source: tagSuggestion.ttAdapter()
    });

});
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong, but typeahead isn't working with prefetch.

Comment: You might want to rename your json file to `ajax.json-colors.json` instead of `ajax.json-colors.php`, and make sure the path exists. Inspect if there are any console errors.

Comment: @ArathiSreekumar the database should be dynamic and there is no problem receiving the data into the javascript object

Comment: So you can see the data coming through to the frontend? The prefetch does make an ajax request?

Comment: @ArathiSreekumar yes, the data is coming and the prefetch does an ajax request

Comment: The plugin was last updated ~2 years ago, I'd suggest switching to [autocomplete.js](https://github.com/algolia/autocomplete.js)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something along the lines of this might work:

```
var tagSuggestion = new Bloodhound({
    datumTokenizer: function(d) {
        return Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace(d.name);
    },
    queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
    limit: 10,
    prefetch: {
        url: 'ajax.json-colors.php',
        filter: function (data) {
            //console.log(data.response) --> see if this is your data in example above
            return $.map(data.response, function (tags) {
                return {
                    name: tags.name
                };
            });
        }
    }
});
```

This is assuming the data coming back in prefetch is in the form of a response object with data in it. Might need to modify based on what `data` is, that gets passed to the filter.

This is if ajax response is a key value with the key being 'response'. Without a working fiddle I can only guess at issues.

Answer (score 0):

finaly the problem was solved using the remote function and changing my code for the following:

```
var tagSuggestion = new Bloodhound({
    datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('value'),
    queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
    remote: {
        url: 'ajax.json-colors.php?query=%QUERY',
        wildcard: '%QUERY'
    }
});

$('.typeahead').typeahead({
    minLength: 2,
    highlight: true
},
{
    name: 'search',
    display: 'value',
    source: tagSuggestion
});
```

it seems that typeahead doesn't work with php files as the prefetch source and accepts only json text files.